# Cross domain messaging using window.name?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, cross-domain

The characteristic of `window.name` which allows us to do XDM , is the fact that the name never changes. (even if we redirect.).

- Does this feature (of not changing) is supported/[continue to be supported] in all browsers ?
- More general question , why doesn't it change ?  - (even after redirection ) *The common sense claims that if i navigated to another location , the window object should be reset....*

I couldn't find it on MDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this feature (of not changing) is supported/[continue to be supported] in all browsers ?

I can't find any documentation suggesting that it has been locked down

> More general question , why doesn't it change ? - (even after redirection ) The common sense claims that if i navigated to another location , the window object should be reset

If it changed, then as soon as you linked to a new document in it:

```
<a target="myWindow" href="http://example.com">
```

… then a subsequent attempt to link to a different document in the window would cause a new window to be opened because there would no longer be one named `myWindow`.

Comment: The target attribute, if present, must be a valid browsing context name or keyword. It gives the name of the browsing context that will be used. — http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-target

Comment: A tab or **window** in a Web browser typically contains a browsing context, as does an iframe or frames in a frameset. — http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context